# How to check if a string is 8 digits long?

Tags: javascript

Tell me how to do it correctly Checking less than 8 characters. The first time I just did it on an empty line. Next, there is a check of less than 8 characters, it is lit red, if more, it is lit green. The problem is how to make it less than 8 digits and turn red. And when it is greater than or equal to 8 digits, it burned green.

```
function validatePassword(password) {
            const reg = (/^(?=.*[0-9]{8,})$/);
            return reg.test(String(password).toLowerCase());
        };  
    const checkPassword = () => {
            const inputPassword = document.querySelector('.form__input-password');
            const inputPasswordText = inputPassword.value
            const examValidatePassword = validatePassword(inputPasswordText);
            const passwordStar = document.querySelector('.form__input-password-star');
            const passwordTitle = document.querySelector('.form__password-title');
            const textPasswordWrong = document.querySelector('.form__input-password-validate-text-wrong');
        
            if (inputPasswordText.length === 0) {
                inputPassword.style.border = '1px solid #ff0000';
                passwordStar.style.color = 'red';
                passwordStar.style.opacity = '100'
                passwordTitle.style.color = 'red';
                textPasswordWrong.style.opacity = '100';
                textPasswordWrong.innerHTML = '* Поле обязательно для заполнения';
                checkValidatePass = false;
                userPassword = "";
            } else if (examValidatePassword str.length => 8 ) {
                inputPassword.style.border = '1px solid #ff0000';
                passwordStar.style.color = 'red';
                passwordStar.style.opacity = '100';
                passwordTitle.style.color = 'red';
                textPasswordWrong.style.opacity = '100';
                textPasswordWrong.innerHTML = '* Пароль должен содержать как минимум 8 символов';
                checkValidatePass = false;
                userPassword = "";
            } else {
                inputPassword.style.border = '1px solid green';
                passwordStar.style.color = '#787878';
                passwordTitle.style.color = 'green';
                passwordStar.style.opacity = '0';
                textPasswordWrong.style.opacity = '0';
                checkValidatePass = true;
                userPassword = inputPasswordText;
            }
        };
```

Comment: check this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Comment: `else if (examValidatePassword.length >= 8) {`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work(

Comment: Or actually `else if (examValidatePassword.length < 8) {` to test it is less than 8

Comment: But no need since you use a regexp to test it is minimum 8 already

Comment: And opacity is a [float from 0 to 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) not a string from '0' to '100'

Comment: Why not just do `passwordStar.classList.toggle("error",!examValidatePassword); textPasswordWrong.classList.toggle("error",!examValidatePassword);` etc and have error be opacity 1 and color red?

Comment: When you enter at least one digit, it immediately turns green, but it is necessary that when the 7 digit was entered, it remains red